# heap update key

Tags: php, data-structures

Short description:
Is there a fast way to put heap back to order, after updating several values?
I know there's an easy way to fix one misplaced key, if I know the key beforehand. There's also easy way to restore all the heap to order, using the same function the heap was created at the first place.

I'm looking for something between those two.

Is there a way to restore order of, lets say, two misplaced keys? (assuming I know which keys they are)

And long description:
I need a priority queue (heap) in PHP. There seems to be good set of SPL functions for that, but I didn't find support for update().
By update($key), i mean a function, which would allow me to restore the heap order after changing $key => $value.
So I wrote my own heap with update() function and it works just fine.
I already have the key to be updated from another place, so I don't have to search through heap to find it, just calling update($key). 
But I'm looking for some optimisation.

The way I use it in that script is: I create a heap, fill it up and then repeatedly do this:

1. look at root key, get a value of it
2. use the value as a parameter in some function, lets call it F()
3. this function F() then does some stuff and during that, it might update several values in the heap.
4. jump to step 1

Most of the time, the function F() updates two keys: the root and one more key. But occationaly, it might update less or more (it can even update all keys sometimes, it's rare though)

I don't really like the fact, that function F() has to call update() function after each change. For some reasons (one key might be updated repeatedly in one run of the F() function), it would be better, if the function "manually" changed the value of the key and then, after it finishes, it would return an array of keys, which were updated. Then, all those updated keys would be put in right positions all at once.

So, update() function would have to be modified to work with array of keys, instead of one key. But I'm not sure it is possible, nor how to do it.

Comment: Some code would be helpful here, it's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know what code should I past here, so I might explain what it is for: It is a simulation script for an online game, where the heap represents time, members of a heap represent next occurence of events in time and root of the heap represents nearest event. Those events are repetitive, so after root event gets executed, it is moved further in the heap, representing next occurence of the event, and new root appears at the top, representing new nearest event. But many of those events change the exact timing of other events a bit, based on quite complex simulation.